# UnsatisfiedLinkError when running android project with tflite

Tags: java, android, c++, tensorflow, android-ndk

I'm trying to use `libtensorflow.so` in my c++ project so I can use it in my android wrapper. My project is a c++ project at it's core but uses different UI binders mainly android NDK. I've checked the [official build docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm) and ran this command: `bazel build --config=elinux_aarch64 -c opt //tensorflow/lite/c:libtensorflowlite_c.so` which built with no proplems. Then I got the necessary include directories mainly `tensorflow` and `flatbuffers` from the tensorflow source directory I got from github (Where I ran bazel).

Then I've added it to my android cmake like so:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../third-party/include/tflite)

add_library(libtensorflowlite 
            SHARED 
            IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(
        libtensorflowlite 
        PROPERTIES 
        IMPORTED_LOCATION 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../third-party/libs/tflite/arm64-v8a/libtensorflowlite.so
)
...
target_link_libraries(
...
#tflite
libtensorflowlite
...
)
```

When I run my project I get this output on logcat:

```
2023-02-13 11:37:01.222  3987-3987  ample.nerveblo          com.example.my_proj                W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2023-02-13 11:37:01.223  3987-3987  ample.nerveblo          com.example.my_proj                W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2023-02-13 11:37:01.229  3987-3987  AndroidRuntime          com.example.my_proj                D  Shutting down VM
2023-02-13 11:37:01.231  3987-3987  AndroidRuntime          com.example.my_proj                E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.my_proj, PID: 3987
                                                                                                    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libm.so.6" not found: needed by /data/app/~~0XEVJKwYyglTdlVABYHPjw==/com.example.my_proj-8OVBEONU7K3bv0RuyroYKA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libtensorflowlite.so in namespace classloader-namespace
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1077)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:998)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1656)
                                                                                                        at com.example.my_proj.My_proj.<clinit>(My_proj.java:40)
                                                                                                        at com.example.my_proj.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8326)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8306)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1347)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4212)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4403)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:104)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2498)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8855)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
2023-02-13 11:37:01.246  3987-3987  Process                 com.example.My_proj                I  Sending signal. PID: 3987 SIG: 9
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (3987) for package com.example.my_proj ----------------------------
2023-02-13 11:37:01.268  1161-2253  WindowManager           system_server                        E  win=Window{a2940e9 u0 Splash Screen com.example.my_proj EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6283 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6264 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:6089 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord$$ExternalSyntheticLambda14.accept:2 java.util.ArrayList.forEach:1262 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.onAnimationFinished:8340 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.postApplyAnimation:6016
```

Comment: You probably compiled a shared library for Android which had its own dependencies (libm.so) which aren't there in CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @kiner_shah I've searched the library a bit which seems to be `math.h`, which apparently can be included with `-lm` flag but adding it changed nothing...

Comment: Make sure to clean and rebuild your project after making changes to CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @kiner_shah no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was I ran with the `--config=elinux_aarch64` flag not `--config=android_arm64`. Using the android version of the command caused a bunch of more problems but I think it's the right way to go. The new problems are mainly caused by me trying to cross-compile an aarch64 code on a linux amd machine and it is not fully supported by tensorflow yet as far as I'm concerned. Although I'm not quite sure how someone can compile *on* an aarch64 machine...

If someone has a pre-compiled aarch64 c++ tensorflow lite library links I would appreciate it.

Comment: I am in the middle of a similar project, and getting a similar error message at runtime when I  built the tflite library with cmake. I also tried bazel but haven't tested that build at the runtime yet.... but I had the additional flag ```--fat_apk_cpu=arm64-v8a``` for the bazel command. maybe check that is that already in your bazel.rc or put it in the command line?